# sympy simplify for minimum using inequality not working

Tags: sympy

sympy can't use inequality `a<b` to simplify expression `Min(a,b)` , which results in the following code giving `Min(a,b)` instead of `a`.

```
from sympy import symbols, Min, simplify

# Define symbols
a, b = symbols('a b')

# Assume a < b
inequality = a < b

# Use the simplify function to simplify the expression
simplified_min = simplify(Min(a, b), assumptions=[inequality])

# The result should be "a"
print(simplified_min)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of `simplify` working with assumptions like that. You might try a brief change of variables:

```py
e = var('eps', positive=True)
from sympy.abc import a, b
>>> Min(a,b).subs(a,b-e).subs(e, b - a)
a
```